# How to open .db file and read tables in it using PHP

Tags: php

I am having a test.db file. i Googled about how to open it but didn't find anything good. I don't want to use SQLite or any other tool.

I tried using dba_open() function but it didn't work out and gives an error call to undefined function.

Can anyone suggest some useful resource or idea?

Comment: What kind of DB is that, can you post some code and more information?

Comment: Is the file a microsoft access database?

Comment: @Seçkin, it could be anything, it could be an image called test.db. But we will never know, OP does not want to use ANY database tool.

Comment: @davidkonrad it's a plane! ....

Comment: i extracted this file from cookies.

Answer (score 0):

To use the `DBA` Abstraction Layer functions, they must be [installed and enabled](http://php.net/manual/en/dba.installation.php), either yourself or by your hosting provider.

You also need to make sure that your file is supported by one of the [DBA handlers](http://php.net/manual/en/dba.requirements.php).

Comment: How will i know which DBA handlers my file supports?

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748754/file-extension-db-what-kind-of-database-is-it-exactly can help.