# Opening a Delphi file with unknown encoding

Tags: database, delphi, encoding

I am a web developer by trade, so please excuse my lack of knowledge on how databases are structured in Delphi.

I wish to open database files from a program that I know was written in Delphi, however I do not have access to any source code. The database files have names such as '.IX$', '.TG$', '.VO$', etc..

No matter what encoding I try, it opens with unintelligible characters plus some interspersed plain text (notably the plain text appears to be all the important strings, but they're nested in varying clusters of non-English characters). There appears to be no byte order mark.

Other than sitting here attempting to play cryptographer and matching repeating gibberish, are there any tools that can parse this? I am hoping I'm just missing some obvious answer such as "Oh all Delphi files that end in $ are XYZ and can be evaluated with program ABC"...

Comment: Those are binary files. Unless you know the file structure, you're not going to be able to do anything with them. They're not encoded text, they're binary. Not every file on a computer is text-based. You can't decode an image file as text, either. And questions asking us to find or recommend a tool, software library or other off-site resource that can read them are off-topic here according to the site guidelines, which can be found in the [help].

Comment: Also, FWIW: Files with `$` in the extension typically are temporary files. Find the files without those characters (such as .DB) and search the web for information about that extension.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5748754/62576

Comment: I appreciate your help Ken

Comment: The text strings in an EXE file usually gives some hints in things like error messages and copyright notices for what major components/engines it uses.

Comment: As you are a web developer by trade you may not have picked up on @Brian's useful comment.  If you look at the details of the EXE program made in Delphi with appropriate tools you should be able to find in the import table any run time libraries it loads (DLLs maybe BPLs).  Also compiled into the EXE (probably as resources) may be strings which can help you identify tools which have been used.

Comment: Try to load this files using that program https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DJcR64AL4nOUxwmRXgzOemWIqT_nk8vE/view?usp=sharing if one of the file will open its ClientDataSet files

Comment: I'm unfortunately going to pass on opening an exe with no preview of what it is. Is there a public repository that I can look at?

Comment: And thanks to the additional comments above. When I'm in the office on Monday I will give it a try.